# Amazon S3 track downloaded file in Asynchronous method in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, amazon-s3

During downloading multiple files using following asynchronous method of AWS iOS, I want to keep track which image is downloaded.

Following code is used for asynchronous image download.

```
S3TransferManager *tm = [S3TransferManager new];
S3TransferOperation *downloadFileOperation =  [tm downloadFile:storeFilePath bucket:Bucket key:downloadPath];
```

Above method is in for loop, so there could be `n` images to download.

Delegate method which notify image is downloaded

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response { }
```

But I did not find anything, using which I can manage that which actual image is downloaded. whether it was the firstID image or second one.

Any idea on where I can put some extra data , which can be received on image download ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as, I have to only download content from Amazon s3, I used [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).
(Though this is not maintained since 2011, but I found its very useful and easy to use for my app).

Code Example,

// Initialize network Queue.

```
ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];
[networkQueue reset];
[networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];  //This is where download completion will be notified.
```

//Initialize Request.

```
ASIS3ObjectRequest *request = [ASIS3ObjectRequest requestWithBucket:@"Bucket_Name" key:@"/Path/file"];
```

This is what I was looking, I need all the information about what I am downloading on download completion. This userInfo contains all the data, which is available on download completion.

```
NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Data", @"Key", nil];  
request.userInfo = userInfo;
userInfo = nil;
```

// End of userInfo set.

```
[networkQueue addOperation:request];  // add request in ASINetworkQueue object. We can also add multiple request here.
```

And last,

```
[networkQueue go];    // This will start downloading.
```

// Delegate method, where download completion will be notified

```
- (void)requestDone:(ASIS3Request *)request
{
    NSLog(@"UserInfo : %@", request.userInfo); // Request data, to manage which request is complete.
}
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can set requestTag:

```
S3PutObjectRequest *putObjectRequest = [ [ S3PutObjectRequest alloc ] initWithKey:keyFile inBucket:self.s3BucketName ];
putObjectRequest.requestTag = urlStringFile;
putObjectRequest.filename = fileName;
```

and then analyse it:

```
- (void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest*) request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse*) response
{
    NSLog(@"Upload finished. RequestTag = %@", request.requestTag);
}
```